# How can i redirect all http to https facebook pages?

Tags: facebook, url, https

I want to force all parent windows of my application from this url:
http://apps.facebook.com/app_name/
to this:
https://apps.facebook.com/app_name/

(http to https)

How can i do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this (be warned that this will leave your application without `signed_request`):

```
if (document.location.protocol=='http:'){
  document.location.protocol = 'https:';
}
```

If you do want the parent frame (Facebook itself) to be switched to `HTTPS` as well than you'll need to know the `URL` of your page within application:

```
if (document.location.protocol=='http:'){
  window.top.location = 'https://YOUR_APPLICATION_PAGE_URL'
}
```

You probably know the `URL` pattern for your application and do know the `Canvas URL` of it, so something like this may fit:

```
if (document.location.protocol=='http:'){
  var applicationUrl = 'https://facebook.com/example-application';
  var canvasURL = 'http://example.com/facebook-canvas';
  var currentAppPageUrl = (document.location+'').replace(canvasURL, applicationUrl);
  window.top.location = currentAppPageUrl;
}
```

Comment: I tried to get "window.top.location",
but i guess facebook not alow me get that.

Comment: This is not related to Facebook but Cross-Domain policy of the browser. In short: you're not allowed to get window.top.location only to set it!

Comment: I tried this code:
`<pre>`
if (document.top.protocol=='http:'){
  var applicationUrl = 'https://apps.facebook.com/app_name';
  var canvasURL = 'https://www.app_name.com';
  var currentAppPageUrl = (document.location+'').replace(canvasURL, applicationUrl);
  window.top.location = currentAppPageUrl;
 }
`</pre>`

It's not work.

Comment: Well, this works for my apps. Can you provide me your `app_name` (if it's not private mode, you can remove the comment later) so I'll be able to provide exact code?

Answer (score 0):

Canvas app is at your domain and top is at Facebook domain, so calling window.top.location inside Facebook Canvas app causes cross domain URL access from iframe.

All you need is to catch the exception via try catch block.

```
if (document.location.protocol=='http:'){
    var applicationUrl = 'https://facebook.com/example-application';
    var canvasURL = location.protocol+'//'+location.host+location.pathname;
    var currentAppPageUrl = (document.location+'').replace(canvasURL, applicationUrl);
    try {
        window.top.location = currentAppPageUrl;
    } catch (e) {
    }
}
```